# Optimize leastsq execution order

Tags: python, scipy

I found a very weird thing with my problem. I put the whole file here now replacing the previous one.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
from option_pricer import BS_Call, r_input  
from scipy.optimize import leastsq  

## this function returns the error vector

def res_bs(p):  

    sigma = p  
    err = np.zeros(len(k))  
    for i in range(len(k)):  
        err[i] = (callEu[i]-BS_Call(sigma, r[i], T[i]/360, s[i], k[i] ))/sqrt(len(k))  
    return err

## this function returns the root mean squared error

def rmse_bs(p):

    return sqrt(sum(res_bs(p)**2))  

## this function converts the raw data into variables to be used      
def params_in(options):

    k = options.strk_prc  
    k = pd.np.array(k)  
    T = options.tmy  
    T = pd.np.array(T)  
    s = options.undl_prc  
    s = pd.np.array(s)  
    callEu = options.eur_call_prc  
    callEu = pd.np.array(callEu)  
    callAm = options.ame_call_prc  
    callAm = pd.np.array(callAm)  
    r1 = unique(options.r1)  
    r1 = pd.np.array(r1)      
    r2 = unique(options.r2)  
    r2 = pd.np.array(r2)      
    r3 = unique(options.r3)  
    r3 = pd.np.array(r3)      
    r4 = unique(options.r4)  
    r4 = pd.np.array(r4)      
    r5 = unique(options.r5)  
    r5 = pd.np.array(r5)  
    r = r_input(T, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)  
    return [k, T, s, callEu, callAm, r]  

## the calibration routine
def calib_bs(data):

    tdDays = sorted(set(data.d_td))  
    N = len(tdDays)  
    sigma_implied = np.zeros(N)  
    rmseBS = np.zeros(N)  
    for i in range(N):  
        options = data[data['d_td']==tdDays[i]]  
        global k, T, s, callEu, callAm, r  
        [k, T, s, callEu, callAm, r] = params_in(options)  
        p0 = 0.05    
        sigma_implied[i] = leastsq(res_bs, p0)[0]  
        rmseBS[i] = rmse_bs(sigma_implied[i])  
    return [sigma_implied, rmseBS]  

data = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv")

[sigma, rmseBS] = calib_bs(data)
```

If I execute the above in Spyder directly (pressing "F5"), then the result is just `p0`!
But, if I execute interactively - that is, load the data, define functions, then call calibration function - I would get the right answer!

My intuition tells me this problem relates to the way or the order that Python executes commands. But I do not have knowledge with that.

Can anyone tell me how to modify the code to allow direct execution rather than interactively?

**Appendix:**
I tried the following test and I did not find any problem. That is, the result is correct and it does not depend on how I execute the code, e.g., execute it directly ("F5") or interactively. The "data.csv" file can be anything, I made a matrix with np.arrange(1,41).reshape(20,2) and save that as data.csv

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import pandas as pd
from testFuncs import f  ## f is f(x, p) return x*p, a linear function

```
def ssr(p):

    beta = p  
    err = np.zeros(len(x))  
    for i in range(len(x)):  
        err[i] = ( y[i]-f(x[i],beta) )  
    return err  

def calibration(data):

    l = data.count()[0]
    a = data.a
    a = pd.np.array(a)
    b = data.b
    b = pd.np.array(b)
    par = np.zeros(l/5)
    for i in range(l/5):
        global x, y
        x = a[i*5:(i+1)*5]
        y = b[i*5:(i+1)*5]
        p0 = 1
        par[i] = leastsq(ssr, p0)[0]
    return par

result = calibration(data)
```

Comment: Please show exactly what you have in your file, not just descriptions.

Comment: x0, y0 are not defined in your calibration function. So it takes whatever values you assigned to it last, or should raise an Error if they are not defined in any outer scope.

Comment: @ejk314, thank you for the help. I have put the content of the original .py file here. Look forward to your insights.

Comment: @user333700, thank you for the help. I included an Appendix in the original post for your reference.

Comment: This is a lot of code (and still not enough to exactly reproduce this).

Comment: @BenjaminBannier, thank you for the help. Is it possible that I send you the .py file and a small subset of the data?

Comment: res_bs still uses variables from outer scope. I don't remember what happens in this case in python. Are they set only once at initialization?   I don't remember, because I never do this. It's too painful to keep track of globals or variables from an outer scope. A simple solution would be to define your variables either in a nested function or even better as attributes to a class.

Comment: @user333700, thanks for the thoughtful comments. I am new to python, even newer to OO programming. I will try to explore your suggestions.